# jQuery script taking too much time in IE

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a page with say 120 date boxes. I am using the validate plugin to validate those boxes on page submit. I have written some custom date validation code.

I use the jQuery.validator.addMethod() to create rules and then I use validator.addClassRules() to add those validations to my calendars.

Its running fine in firefox (at times) but in IE as soon as I hit enter it gives a popup saying "A script on this page is causing Internet explorer to slow down...."

can someone please help.

Adding the code too.....

```
/******* This is the input thats there *********/
<input type="text" toDate="${dateRangeModel.toDate}" fromDate="${dateRangeModel.fromDate}" prefill="mm/dd/yyyy" class="calendarInput"  />

/* Checking if its a valid date */
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("isDateValid",function(value, element) { 
                    var re =  /(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])+\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])+\/(19|20)\d\d/;                                      

                    if($(element).is(':hidden') || value.match(re) || value === $(element).attr('prefill')){
                        return true;
                    }
                    else    {
                        return false;
                    }
            }, 'Enter a valid date');


/******** Adding class rule ***********/
$.validator.addClassRules({
                calendarInput: {
                    dateRange:true,
                    isDateValid: true
                }
            });
```

Comment: Use the IE8 profiler to see what's running slow.

Comment: Why would you have 120 date boxes on the same page?! Displaying them all at once would be impossible from a UI/usability perspective anyway - just generate the boxes dynamically and/or reuse one.

Comment: _apparently_, dude is a hit with the ladeez

Comment: IE is slow, compared to Firefox, with JavaScript, but you would need to post your code for use to see what may be happening.

Comment: Did anyone get around fixing this problem? Even I'm facing this one and there are only around 80 fields in my form. I can confirm that its not about custom validations but even the regular $('#id').validate() seems to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for IE specific performance problems is [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/).  They have [quick start tutorials on the site](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/learn/how-it-works.aspx), just fire up your page and see what's taking the most time to execute.

And yes, it's free :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is compile the regular expression outside of the validation call, like

```
var re = new RegExp("(0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])+\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])+\/(19|20)\d\d");
```

and then reuse the same object in all the validation calls rather than constantly rebuilding it. That said, having 120 of pretty much anything on the same page is a UI disaster.

You can shorten up the rest of it (mainly to make it more concise) as well:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isDateValid",function(value, element) { 
    return ($(element).is(':hidden') || value === $(element).attr('prefill') || value.match(re));
}, 'Enter a valid date');
```

I reordered the test in the hopes putting the regex test last would make things a bit faster.